# Is checking both `snapshot.hasData` and `snapshot.data != null` redundant in Flutter's FutureBuilder?

Tags: flutter, dart, future, flutter-futurebuilder

I'm working with Flutter's [`FutureBuilder`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/FutureBuilder-class.html) and came across a pattern where **both** `snapshot.hasData` *and* `snapshot.data != null` are checked before rendering a widget:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: future,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData && snapshot.data != null) {
      return widgetToBuild;
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Icon(Icons.error_outline);
    } else {
      return CircularProgressIndicator();
    }
  }
)
```

Upon examining the source code of [`AsyncSnapshot`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot-class.html), I noticed [that `hasData` is defined](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/hasData.html) as `true` if `data` is not `null`:

```dart
bool get hasData => data != null;
```

Given this implementation, is it redundant to check both `snapshot.hasData` and `snapshot.data != null`? Wouldn't `snapshot.hasData` suffice since it inherently checks if `data` is not `null`?

I am curious if there's a scenario where both checks might be necessary, or if this is just a common misunderstanding in the usage of `FutureBuilder` that developers often mistaken.

Comment: hasData could be that it is done receiving data, but whatever api you could be hitting, a result could be null, so in an instance you could be done and successfully received data, with that data being null.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [`AsyncSnapshot#hasData()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/AsyncSnapshot/hasData.html) comes from [commit fbd4bb9](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/commit/fbd4bb91f666688b138ba1f68b0b45d54e857c5f).

There was a large debate around that in [issue 34545](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/34545#issuecomment-514523060):

> > What if we stop conflating `data == null` and initial data with this discussion altogether -- and simply make the small breaking change of making the data getter throw if hasError is true?
> > I would also get rid of `requireData` and let callers check null themselves.
>
> That does sound ok to me - with one inconvenience: The conflating of `data == null` and initial data is kinda baked in to the API in the `hasData` getter (which just checks if data is null, but null may be valid data...).
> I wonder if we should get rid of `hasData` as well and just tell people if you want to know if data is not null, just check data?

I suspect this is why you see code like:

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: future,
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasData) {
      if (snapshot.data != null) {
        return widgetToBuild; // Data is available and not null
      } else {
        // Handle null data scenario, e.g., show a message
        return Text("No data available");
      }
    } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
      return Icon(Icons.error_outline); // An error occurred
    }
    return CircularProgressIndicator(); // Still waiting for data
  }
)
```

But in the current state, it is still redundant.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's redundant, you are right: if you replace the `AsyncSnapshot` code in the first piece you posted, it would look like this

```
if (snapshot.data != null && snapshot.data != null) {
```

Regarding possible `null` results from a `future`, it happened once in some code of mine (due to an unexpected circumstance), and the `FutureBuilder` got stuck on the `CircularProgressIndicator` because the data was never detected.
So, unless something changed, I think that `null`-returning futures are not to be used with `FutureBuilder`.

Answer (score 0):

The `snapshot.hasData` is a handy check that does more than just see if there's data. It essentially tells you, "Hey, not only do I have data, but also my future is resolved and everything's cool!" It's a green light indicating that your future has successfully completed and there's some data to show.

Think of `snapshot.hasData` as your trusty guard, ensuring that everything went as planned, and `snapshot.data != null` as a meticulous inspector, making sure what you got is actually what you need. Depending on your situation, you might need just the guard, or both the guard and the inspector, to ensure everything is just perfect.

If your future can never return null upon successful completion, then `snapshot.hasData` is your go-to check. It's like having confidence in the promise that if the future is done, data is guaranteed. On the flip side, if there's a chance of getting a null even when everything goes smoothly, adding `snapshot.data != null` is like having that extra layer of assurance.

Comment: The "layer of assurance" is only in the developer's mind, though. That piece of code is clearly redundant, and does not provide anything additional. Instead, it probably works the other way: the developer might think that a Future can return null in a FutureBuilder and still get the results they expect...instead they get an error and don't understand why.